# Delete all files with names longer than 100 characters?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filenames

A beta software I installed accidentally created a log file with file name longer than 100 characters in each folder. It's taking a very long time to delete them one by one

Is it possible to bulk delete all the files whose names are longer or equal to 100 characters without deleting files shorter than 100 characters?

Comment: can you please clarify your question? are you talking about 100 characters or 100 units of size? what folders did it create these files in? etc.

Comment: I assume it's a file name that's like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.txt" (as a length). Do they have a common extension?

Comment: I'm talking about 100 characters. The extension is ".log". I edited the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, if this lists your files:

```
gci -file -recurse | ?{$_.name.length -gt 100} | select name | ft -Wrap
```

Then this will delete them:

```
gci -file -recurse | ?{$_.name.length -gt 100} | remove-item
```

Comment: this command does the job. PS. i'm new to powershell

Answer (score 2):

Run the below command in PowerShell

```
ls | where { $_.Name.Length -ge 100 } | rm -WhatIf
```

`ls` is one of the aliases for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) and `rm` is [`Remove-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Remove-Item?view=powershell-6). If the files you want to delete is not in the current folder then put the full path to the folder after `ls`

After confirming the files are correct remove the `-WhatIf` part to do the real deletion. If you also want to delete files in subdirectories add `-Recurse` to `ls`

Comment: It's comfirming that it want to remove files with filename below 100 characters. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @prouser135 it'll remove files with filenames longer than or equal to 100 characters. For more than 100 characters use `-ge 101` or `-gt 100`. But I missed the `BaseName` or `Name` to get the filename without or with extension